# Subsetting data of multiple years

Tags: r, split, subset

I have a dataset with daily price data for years 2003 - 2019. I want to create a subset from this having data for specified years, say 2011-2015. I am using the subset function but when I mention the interval of years, the subsetted data has data for only 1 in 7 days instead of all days for the mentioned years.

```
sub <- subset(data, format(as.Date(data$Date),"%Y")==c(2011:2015))
```

I have tried split function but that creates a list of data frames, which I don't how to use in ggplot or for statistical analysis.

```
sub <- split(data, format(as.Date(data$Date),"%Y")==c(2011:2015))
```

Is there a better way of subsetting so that I am able to extract daily data for the years that I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `Date` is in standard format, you can try :

```
sub_data <- subset(data, as.integer(format(as.Date(Date),"%Y")) %in% 2011:2015)
```

Or with `dplyr` and `lubridate` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

sub_data <- data %>% filter(year(ymd(Date)) %in% 2011:2015)
```

Comment: The first suggestion works fine, thanks! Is there an explanation for why this might be happening though?

Comment: If you want to compare vector of values you should use `%in%`, `==` compares values elementwise.